# Elasticsearch DSL search query not applied on text files while searching

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have two file `st.txt` , `sy.txt`

st.txt

```
was
an
```

sy.txt

```
football,soccer
```

Setting is below

```
new_player_settings = {
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "synonym_en": {
                        "type": "synonym",
                        "synonyms_path": "sy.txt"
                    },
                    "english_stop": {
                        "type": "stop",
                        "stopwords_path": "st.txt"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "english_analyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "english_stop",
                            "synonym_en"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "english_analyzer"
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "english_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

myd is below

```
abc = [
{'id':1, 'name': 'christiano ronaldo', 'description': 'football@fifa.com', 'type': 'football'},
{'id':2, 'name': 'lionel messi', 'description': 'soccer@fifa.com','type': 'soccer'},
{'id':3, 'name': 'sachin', 'description': 'was', 'type': 'cricket'}
]
```

DSL query is below

```
{
"query": {
"query_string": {
"fields": ["name^2","description^2","type^4"],
"query": "was football"
}
}}
```

My Output

```
{'took': 2,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 2, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': 3.9233165,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'newplayers',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '1',
    '_score': 3.9233165,
    '_source': {'id': 1,
     'name': 'christiano ronaldo',
     'description': 'football@fifa.com',
     'type': 'football'}},
   {'_index': 'newplayers',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '3',
    '_score': 2.345461,
    '_source': {'id': 3,
     'name': 'sachin',
     'description': 'was',
     'type': 'cricket'}}]}}
```

Expected out

```
id 3 should not present since stopword `was` present, id 2 should present because in synonym football=stopwords
```

Expected

```
{'took': 2,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 2, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': 2.0,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'players',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '1',
    '_score': 2.0,
    '_source': {'id': 1,
     'name': 'christiano ronaldo',
     'description': 'football@fifa.com',
     'type': 'football'}},
   {'_index': 'players',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '2',
    '_score': 2.0,
    '_source': {'id': 2,
     'name': 'lionel messi',
     'description': 'soccer@fifa.com',
     'type': 'soccer'}}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maybe issue is that `sy` and `st` text files which defines your index stop and synonyms are not present in the Elasticsearch cluster**, but I tried with same settings and mappings and the sample data you provided and I was able to get your expected output, as shown below.

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "fields": [
                "name^2",
                "description^2",
                "type^4"
            ],
            "query": "was football"
        }
    }
}
```

And search result with source JSON

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "72796944",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.4051987,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "christiano ronaldo",
                    "description": "football@fifa.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "72796944",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.4051987,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "lionel messi",
                    "description": "soccer@fifa.com"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**Would be great if you can share the output of explain API, which you can get by appending the `?explain=true` in your search endpoint, to debug further**

Update: As discussed in the comment,issue is not happening when these words are defined in the setting itself, so its issue is that file content is not being updated properly in Elasticsearch.

Comment: can i have different file in index right? or in entire cluster i should not have st.txt only one time i could use st.txt

Comment: @sim, sorry didn't get you, but instead of file you can have these words as these are less, as part of your index setting itself, adding the example of it in my answer

Comment: can you explain this `Maybe issue is that sy and st text files which defines your index stop and synonyms are not present in the Elasticsearch cluster,`

Comment: I got output  if i am adding directly to the settings,  but my file size is huge, that is why i m adding files

Comment: @sim, ahh i see, so it means issue is the file, how are you adding these files to Elasticsearch cluster?

Comment: its from python api

Comment: @sim, no you need to manually store these files in the Elasticsearch nodes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246336/discussion-between-amit-and-sim).